# Is it possible to filter out paths from Swagger UI 3?

Tags: javascript, swagger-ui

Trying to get swagger-ui embedded on Zendesk articles, need to display only one 'path' per article

I used the SwaggerUIBundle to load it in Zendesk, I get the whole OAS 3.0 to be displayed, but I want to be able to select which paths are displayed per article

```html
<script src="{{asset 'swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js'}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset 'swagger-ui-bundle.js'}}"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "{{asset 'atlas-swagger.json'}}",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset.slice(1)
    ],
  deepLinking: true
  })

  window.ui = ui
}
</script>
```

As stated, this is displaying the whole thing, as expected, and I believe I will have to make a function on that script to pass along which path I want to be displayed, but I am burnt out on ideas other than that.

Any suggestions, or knowledge of possibility of filtering the path/operation via swagger config?